# Network disconnect does not throw IOException in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a thread that writes to a TCP socket every 5 sec., connected to a remote TCP port (using Java .net socket, not NIO). For your information I have not configured any timeout (S0,..) on to the socket layer, it's having the default values. If the network cable connected to remote TCP port 
is removed my java thread is not getting any IO exception, rather it keeps writing to the socket.

Can somebody guide me why am I not getting those exceptions? I guess write method should through IOException while trying to write to the socket every 5 sec.

Regards, Rajib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely an how much you write to the socket, in case you don't flush regurarly. If you write only a couple of bytes every 5 seconds, it may indeed take quite a bit for the buffer to fill and flush automatically. The exception should arise eventually. If you do flush, then there could be another network pipe that you are overlooking, such as WiFi, and the transport just fails over to that one.

Comment: does Java do some internall buffering? the OS certainly won't queue it up for seconds

Comment: Yes, there may well be internal buffering in Java not subject to timeouts. It depends on how exactly the output pipe is configured (which wrappers are used).

Comment: @Marko -  my code snipet - public void writeLine(String line) throws IOException { writer.write(line); writer.flush(); } - I am expecting the IOException if network cable is disconnected.

Comment: Let me ask you this: are you positive that the server has stopped receiving bytes after the cable is unplugged? This is to eliminate my second option.

Comment: @Marko - No, Though we have another thread that reads from the same socket. I have not seen any IOException there too.

Comment: So the TCP connection really is still alive. This is not Java-related, then. It is down to your network setup.

Comment: @Marko - In that case when can we conclude a socket connection is dead if a network cable is unplugged from the remote port? Why can’t the socket.write method take this decision?

Comment: @RajibDeka Because it doesn't know. All it knows in the success case is that it succeeded in moving data from the application into the kernel's socket send buffer, from where it is written asynchronouly to the network by the TCP/IP stack. If you come back later with another write after those writes have definitely failed, you will get an IOException at that point. But, as Marko said, it could take a lot of writes and quite a few seconds.

Comment: @Marko and EJP - Thanks a lot for your valuable replies.